# Konjunktiv II mit Modalverb

Tags: sentence-structure

I have been practicing the "Konjunktiv II mit Modalverb". It all seemed straightforward, simply use "hätte" + infinitive and modal verb at the end:

> Ich hätte früher nachfragen sollen.

Until I met this example in my textbook:

> Du hättest früher anfangen sollen zu packen.

Why is "zu packen" at the end rather than "sollen"?

Is the following incorrect and if so why?

> Du hättest früher anfangen zu packen sollen.

Answer (score 2):

Using the infinitive 'zu' construction can be a little difficult to grasp. The best way to think of it is substituting an object of the sentence for a verb which has no subject - but it also has some special grammatical rules associated with it too.

> Du hättest früher anfangen sollen zu packen.

This is completely correct, because it's fine to move an infinitive to the VERY end of a sentence, almost as if it is its own clause.

> Du hättest früher zu packen anfangen sollen. / Du hättest früher zum Packen anfangen sollen.

Also completely correct.

It's important to think of the infinitive as its own unique and independently standing object/subject, not really as a verb anymore.

> Du hättest früher anfangen (zu packen) sollen.

This doesn't quite work because you can't treat infinitive 'zu packen' as a verb which goes in the place of a verb, but instead treat it as an object with the special property that it may go to the very end in this sentence.

Comment: *zu**m P**acken anfangen* is Southern German. In the North, people would say ***mit** dem Packen*.